# Display image and text on runtime, android?

Tags: android, textview, imageview, runtime

I want to display image and text at runtime of the activity.
Similarly just like chat happening in WHATSAPP.
I displaying the text in textview and image in imageview.
The problem i am facing is I want to show both of them on the same activity with scroll
For eg:

```
image
text
text
image
text
image
image
```

Which layout or control should i use to display like this?

Comment: Starting with an Android tutorial should do the trick. http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Answer (score 1):

add both like this..

```
LinearLayout linearLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
 linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp=new   
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.settext("test");
linearLayout.addView(imageView,tv);

ImageView imageView= new ImageView(this);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitMap);
imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
imageView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF00FF);
//linearLayout=LinearLayout+imageView;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams Iv=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
linearLayout.addView(imageView,Iv);
setContentView(linearLayout,vp);
```